# How to get access to Nintendo Switch development environment?

Tags: nintendo

I would like to make game for Nintendo Switch.

I have been searching for an SDK of the same, but I couldn't find any. The only thing I found was that I can use Unreal Engine or Unity to make games for Nintendo Switch.

However I don't want to use any of these game engines and instead want to code from scratch, making my own game engine in the process.

Isn't there a C/C++ (or any language) sdk which will allow me to make games for Nintendo Switch without using Unreal/Unity or any other game engine ?

Comment: How about MonoGame? http://nintendoeverything.com/monogame-software-is-compatible-with-switch/

Comment: Big companies usually get a developement kit or API to develop on platforms.

Comment: @Bálint Where can I get the aforementioned development kit or API?

Comment: @jhocking I don't want to use some game engine. I want to learn by making my own.

Comment: @Ishan If you've successfully registered as a Switch developer, contact your account manager.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I registered as an Individual. My goal is to learn to make games for the Nintendo Switch.

Comment: Sign in, make sure you've completed all NDAs, and look at your available platform SDKs in the portal. If you don't have access to the Switch you'll need to contact somebody to give you access. This likely requires offering them some information about your project.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you need to [register with Nintendo as a developer](https://developer.nintendo.com/register):

> Register for access to Nintendo developer tools and resources to create and publish games and applications for current Nintendo platforms. Resources are provided for multiple development environments including HTML5, Unity and native C++ software development.

So yes, there is a native C++ SDK. But as far as I know at the present, it's only provided by Nintendo directly.

Comment: I have just registered on the nintendo developer portal. There are two sections for wii U and 3DS. I can't find a link anywhere to download a sdk for Switch. For that matter I can't find any information related to Switch at all on there.

Comment: They haven't released open access to an sdk for the Switch yet.

Comment: Currently you have to send a direct message via Nintendo Developer Portal to get access to the Switch development environment.